# one sitemap file to images/videos/urls/mobile

Tags: seo, google-search, sitemap, xml

My web site is writing sitemaps dynamically when a user created a post. But I have a problem with sitemap types. I have to write separately to `sitemap_image.xml`,`sitemap_url.xml`,`sitemap_video.xml` files when a user write a post and upload images and videos to it.

**My Question is:-**

Can I write all things to one sitemap file under google SEO rules.?

**Example**

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/page1.html</loc>
      <image:image>
         <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>
         <image:title>Grey cat on the table</image:title>
         <image:license>https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/</image:license>
         <image:geo_location>Berlin, Germany</image:geo_location>
         <image:caption>Funny cat on the table is looking at photographer.</image:caption>
      </image:image>
      <video:video>            
         <video:thumbnail_loc>http://example.com/thumb1.jpg
         </video: thumbnail_loc>
         <video:title>Clown in the garden</video:title>
         <video:description>Crazy clown is riding a rabbit.</video:description>    
         <video:content_loc>http://www.example.com/video1.mp4</video:content_loc>
      </video:video>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

Thanks in advanced for any help and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to have one sitemap that includes pages, images and video. It is likely a better format to have 3 different sitemaps for each type, but if this is taking up a lot of constraints on your server, then one sitemap for all should be valid.

> You can use a separate sitemap to list images, or you can add image
>   information to an existing sitemap.
>   https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en

---

> Here is a more complex sitemap that includes a single URL, as well as
>   image and video file information for resources on that page:
>
> xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
>   xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
>
> ```
> <loc>http://www.example.com/foo.html</loc> 
> <image:image>
>    <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
>    <image:caption>Dogs playing poker</image:caption>
> </image:image>
> <video:video>
>   <video:content_loc>
>     http://www.example.com/video123.flv
>   </video:content_loc>
>   <video:player_loc allow_embed="yes" autoplay="ap=1">
>     http://www.example.com/videoplayer.swf?video=123
>   </video:player_loc>
>   <video:thumbnail_loc>
>     http://www.example.com/thumbs/123.jpg
>   </video:thumbnail_loc>
>   <video:title>Grilling steaks for summer</video:title>  
>   <video:description>
>     Cook the perfect steak every time.
>   </video:description>
> </video:video>   </url> </urlset>
> ```
>
> source:
>   https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&ref_topic=4581190
>   under XML dropdown